# Connect to apche spark hive remotely through jdbc client like Squirrel SQL

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, hive, squirrel-sql

I have a running spark cluster installed with hive.I am able to run SQL queries through org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext locally via beeline.Hive thriftserver is running.

But I want to know how to connect to this hive metastore from a remote computer through jdbc without having installed hive all over again in this remote system.

Please suggest what exact driver would be needed and any jdbc client application like Squirrel SQL Client.

Answer (score 0):

The following jars, will help(for cdh distribution)

```
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.4.4-tests.jar
hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.4.4.jar
hadoop-core-2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.4.4.jar
hive-exec-1.1.0-cdh5.4.4.jar
hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.4.4-standalone.jar
hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.4.4.jar
hive-service-1.1.0-cdh5.4.4.jar
libfb303-0.9.0.jar
libthrift-0.9.0.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
```

Comment: It's not a cdh distribution.

Comment: Hive JDBC jars can also be downloaded from Hive's official website with https://hive.apache.org/downloads.html Let's say you downloaded a.mbbsindia.com/hive/hive-2.0.0/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin.tar.gz, after downloading, unzip and go to the lib folder. There you must be able to see all jars. Use them.